# Valor devuelto por odbc_execute

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, mssql

Tengo en un W7x32 instalado XAMPP con la versión 5.6.40 de PHP, el código que os pongo mas abajo funciona bien pero me da la siguiente advertencia "Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Ejecutando SQL directamente, sin cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecute in..." que para mi es muy clara, el SP no devuelve registros, pero quiero evitar que salga ¿ me podríais ayudar ?, gracias

```
<?php 
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/web/func/connect.php');
 $params['direccion'] = 'kk1@kk1.com' ;
 $params['idcontrol'] = 123456;
 $sql = "EXEC SProcedure @direccion = ?, @idcontrol = ?";
 $pstmt=odbc_prepare($con,$sql);
 if (!$pstmt) {
    echo "Falló odbc_prepare";
    die;
 }
 $res =odbc_execute($pstmt,$params);
 if (!$res) {
   echo "Falló odbc_execute";
   die;
```

}
?>

Comment: Me parece que el problema se debe a que estas enviando los parámetros con nombre. Proba hacerlo así: `$params = ['kk1@kk1.com', 123456];`

Comment: gracias -Marcos, más tarde lo pruebo

Comment: Hola Marcos. He probado como me has sugerido y de una tercera forma y nada, sigue saliendo la misma advertencia, como te decía el SP se ejecuta correctamente
    
`$params1=['kk1@kk1.com',123456];
$sql = "EXEC SP ?,?";
$pstmt=odbc_prepare($con,$sql);
$res=odbc_execute($pstmt,$params1);
`
esta es la otra forma

`$params2=array();
$sql = "EXEC SP 'kk1@kk1.com',1234567";
$pstmt=odbc_prepare($con,$sql);
$res=odbc_execute($pstmt,$params2);`
`

Comment: Este error podría ocurrir por tres motivos: 1. No se están autorizadas las conexiones remotas (no sé si aplique a tu contexto); 2. Problemas con el firewall o el puerto donde corre la BD; 3. Falta por instalar algún controlador